# How can I create multiple interfaces of the same name in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a series of files to teach students interfaces, and each one will have an interface called `Recycle` in it. However, when I get to the second file, Eclipse gives me an error saying `Recycle` has already been defined. Here is roughly what my code looks like:

```
public class Example101
{
    //methods here
}

interface Recycle
{
    //abstract methods here
}
```

I'd really like to keep the interfaces in the same files as the example classes.

Comment: Put your interfaces into different packages.

Comment: *to teach students interfaces*.. you can make the interface static and place it in the same file where the class is

Comment: Consider learning the language before attempting to teach it.

Comment: @Eugene Interfaces are always implicitly static. Perhaps you mean define them as nested classes?

Comment: @Boann yes nested, why did I say static? hmm.. thx for the correction

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 1):

You can define types inside other types, using them as mini packages contained within one file:

```
public class Example101 {
    interface Recycle {}
    static class X implements Recycle {}
}
```

One thing you can't do is have the outer class `Example101` itself implement an interface declared inside it. So to implement the interface you'll probably want another class declared inside `Example101` too.

Member classes like `X` should be declared static, unless you want them bound to a created instance of the outer class `Example101`. To also declare the `Recycle` interface static is valid but redundant; member interfaces are always static ([JLS §8.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)). Alternatively, if you make the outer type `Example101` an interface, *all* its member types are implicitly static ([JLS §9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5)).

Answer (score 0):

Create packages.

Create the interfaces in the packages.